# converting from python requests method of http auth to aiohttp.BasicAuth

Tags: python-requests, aiohttp

I have a working HTTP post request:

```
`requests.post('http://' + str(ip_address) + addrsuffix, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(username, password), data='payload')`
```

I'm trying to convert this request to use to asyncio, but using aiohttp I get unauthorised 401 status as a reply.

This is what I tried. I was expecting this to just work, using the BasicAuth username and password method.

```
async def post_request(session, ip, username, password, data):
    digest_auth = aiohttp.BasicAuth(username, password)
    url = f'http://{ip}/addrsuffix/'
    headers = {CONTENT_TYPE: 'application/json'}
    try:
        print(f'{username}, {password}, {data}, {digest_auth}')
        async with session.post(url, auth=digest_auth, headers=headers, json=data) as resp:
            if resp.status == 200:
                print(f'Successful post request to {ip}')
            else:
                print(f'Error {resp.status} for post request to {ip}')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error: {e} for post request to {ip}')
```

when I look at how the original python requests method encodes the auth data, I get:

`<requests.auth.HTTPDigestAuth object at 0x<a_hex_string> >`

but the new aiohttp.BasicAuth method produces:

`BasicAuth(login='myusername', password='mypass', encoding='latin1')`

It seems to me to be the way it is presenting the credentials as "login" (but I might be wrong).
Can I please get guidance on how to achieve the same auth method as the requests.auth produces?
I've tried to read aiohttp's documentation on BasicAuth but find it hard to comprehend.

Answer (score 1):

Happily answering my own dumb question: aiohttp doesn't support Digest Authentication.

So I stumbled on httpx, which seems to work great for this purpose.